# Image processing to determine phone's 2D position

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm trying to track the 2D position of an Android device in mid-air. From what I've read on here and elsewhere, doubly-integrating accelerometer readings to get positional values is a process prone to excessive and unavoidable sensor noise.

My thought was that I could instead use the device's camera. Scale-based positional measurements, in the sense of meters or feet, don't matter to me as much as relative ones do, so my plan is as follows:

1. We deem the initial location (0, 0), and capture the camera's output frame.
2. We capture every subsequent frame as the phone moves through space.
3. For each subsequent frame, we use image processing algorithms to determine the approximate offset of the new image (in pixels) from the previous image, and update our location accordingly.

So my question is whether the image quality from a modern Android phone would be sufficient to accomplish this. Obviously the captured environment can't change  over time or be too chromatically homogenous, but these aren't issues for my purpose.

If it is indeed feasible, what image processing techniques would be effective in this case?

Comment: FWIW, I think I'm looking for something like _Optical Flow_ algs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called [SLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping), it is not an easy problem although image quality (assuming you are using a modern phone) is probably not a major hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Using image processing is some orders of magnitude more effort than reading sensors, and since you have no experience here this will take weeks.  So you should try the sensors first, if it really doesn't work you have wasted hours, but if it works you have saved weeks.  In particular if you have smooth motion the sensors should give pretty accurate results. Depending on your specific motion characteristics there may be better methods available than simple integration, the general keyword here is sensor-fusion, a particularly simple and effective method is called Kalman-filter.